# React component re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning react and I'm building this project that currently is very small but the Products component keep re-rendering.

As you can see I have a `console.log(products);` and in the console i see it printing 4 times.

> How can I avoid this re-rendering?

```
1. []
2. []
3. [...data here]
4. [...data here]
```

Network tab only shows one call to fetch the data. So that's good.

**APP.JS**

```
const app = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Products />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**PRODUCTS.JS**

```
const Products = props => {

    const products = useSelector(state => state.products);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const onLoadProducts = useCallback(() => dispatch(actionCreators.onLoadProducts()), [dispatch]);


    useEffect(() => {
        onLoadProducts();
    }, [onLoadProducts]);

    const flag = products.length > 0 ? 'YAY' : 'NAY';
    console.log(products);
    return (
        <p>{flag}</p>
    )
}

export default React.memo(Products);
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : null || compose;

const store = createStore(productsReducer, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I feel like I don't even need the React.memo. I added it to see if my issue goes away but it didn't

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It's either a prop or state change, so if you get stuck make a useEffect hook which prints a console log when a prop value or state value changes and figure out what is changing and causing a re-render, once you figure that out it should be fairly obvious what is causing it

Comment: @dwjohnston added the question to the "question" :)

Comment: Hey devpato can you add the index.js file ? Where you are rendering the app to the dom element

Comment: @YashJoshi added :)

Comment: Cool I got the issue. Check this link please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825649/why-my-simple-react-component-print-console-twice/60825885#60825885

Comment: @devpato Don't rely on the number of renders because react can call render phase method multiple times to detect side effects :)

Comment: @YashJoshi thank you sir! I upvoted your answer

Comment: @YashJoshi to make sure im understanding what you are saying is that it's okay for me to leave strict mode on my app and let it detect side effects? it wont affect my performance of my app

Comment: Yeah, you can keep it as it is, it won't affect in production mode. This happens only in development mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<React.StrictMode>` Comp. It should fix the issue.

Please check this issue. This answers your question [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1297)

Comment: I did that what you have in your code and it didn't work. I keep having the same issue :(

Comment: Pleae check the stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61328285/react-component-rendering-twice-when-using-usestate-hook/61328493#61328493

Comment: that didn't work either. I removed disabled devtools from my project

Comment: Try removing the strict mode

Comment: Hey @jagrati Just to let you know this is because of React.StrictMode, react in the development mode calls render phase lifecycle multiple times to detect side-effects

Comment: @YashJoshi Yeah this is because of the strict mode.

Comment: ahhhhh yeeessss that was the solution! wow very interesting. Now I see it printing twice. The first is an empty array [] (initial value) then array with data once the call is completed. That is normal behavior right?

Comment: @Jagrati feel free to update your answer so i can mark it as correct